# Mysql result in terminal not shown properly

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I am making a query and get this representation on the terminal screen:

```
mysql> select id, category_name from invoices LIMIT 1;
+------+---------------+
| id   | category_name |
+------+---------------+
|9 | London PA
+------+---------------+
```

instead of :

```
+------+---------------+
| id   | category_name |
+------+---------------+
|9     | London PA     |
+------+---------------+
```

When I am using query vertical format [\G] and everything seems OK.

```
mysql> select id, category_name from invoices LIMIT 1 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 6819
category_name: London PA
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What's your os and mysql client version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Hint: make sure that the encoding you use for your text and your client terminal one are in sync

Comment: @AlmaDo How can I verify it?

Comment: use `show create table` and it will show your table/column encoding. Then just set your terminal into that encoding and you're pretty much done